# How to build a macro that can copy a range of cells and insert rows with new date?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a spreadsheet each month that has 294 rows for each day of the month, excluding weekend dates. What I want to do is to be able to copy the range of rows for each Friday, and copy and paste the data for the missing Saturday and Sunday of each week. I have found a macro that finds missing dates and inserts a row for those dates, but do not know how to copy a range of cells while changing the date.

This is the macro I found in another topic that adds in rows for missing dates.

```
Sub insertMissingDate()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = wks.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

'Work bottom up since we are inserting new rows
For I = lastRow To 3 Step -1
    curcell = wks.Cells(I, 3).Value
    prevcell = wks.Cells(I - 1, 3).Value

    'Using a loop here allows us to bridge a gap of multiple missing dates
    Do Until curcell - 1 = prevcell Or curcell = prevcell
        'Insert new row
        wks.Rows(I).Insert x1ShiftDown

        'Insert missing date into new row
        curcell = wks.Cells(I + 1, 3) - 1
        wks.Cells(I, 3).Value = curcell
    Loop
Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
wks.Rows(I - 1).Copy
```

Before this one:

```
wks.Rows(I).Insert xlShiftDown
```

**Update (based on comments)**

```
Sub AddDataWeekends()

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim x As Long

    For x = lRow To 2 Step -294

        If Weekday(Cells(x, 1), vbSunday) = 6 Then
            Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Copy
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(294 * 2).Insert xlShiftDown
            Cells(x + 1, 1).Resize(294).Value = Cells(x, 1) + 1
            Cells(x + 1, 1).Offset(294).Resize(294).Value = Cells(x, 1) + 2
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, it looks like the only thing left is to figure out how to copy a range of cells and inserting instead of just one.

Comment: @koch11 - this copies the whole row, do you only want certain columns in the row? If so, which ones?

Comment: Each date on the spreadsheet has 294 rows of data. What I am trying to do is copy all 294 with Friday's date, and inserting them in for Saturday and Sunday. So the final result will be 294 rows for Saturday and 294 rows for Sunday that match the data for Friday. Currently the macro copies 1 of 294 rows for Friday, and inserts one row with Saturday and Sundays dates.

Comment: When I tested this macro I listed a bunch of weekday dates. When I ran it inserted Saturday and Sunday lines for each Friday line and filled the proper date. Are you saying all 294 rows are only Friday dates?

Comment: Yes sorry, there are 294 rows associated with each date. Each line is a different item occurring on that date. Over the weekend I want to copy all 294 lines for both Saturday and Sunday. Thanks again for looking at this with me.

Comment: @koch11 - is the date on each of the 294 associated rows? say in column A or something? its like date | item1 | item 2 in columns A,B,C?

Comment: Yes the date is included in each row. So row 1 has the date in column C, transaction data in column's D-S, and than row 2 has the same date in column C, 2nd transaction data in column's D-S and so forth.